# Surround Sound is Louder Playing FM Radio

Tags: theater, home

I have a surround sound that I use that's hooked up to my tv to listen to music through my laptop and play rockband on my Xbox. I have a white and red rca cable hooked up from the receiver to the back of the tv and an hdmi cable plugged into the laptop when I am listening to music and then switch the same hdmi cable to my xbox when I want to play rockband. Recently when playing I switched over to the regular fm radio on my surround sound and it was twice as loud and super brassy. How can I get the volume and sound to sound as loud as the fm radio does? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about home audio.

Answer (score 1):

This a sound design forum, concerning the edit and mix of sound/music in sync to picture or images. Your question, although stated clearly is not exactly a topic of interest to most users. Have you considered contacting the website of your setup/brand?

happy new year